# System Monitor and top reporting wildly different cpu usage for process

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, system-monitor

When I monitor a process using top command it returns the CPU usage for the process like 99.5%. But when I monitor a same process using system monitor (Process tab) for the particular it shows 25%.

- What is the cause of this discrepancy?
- Which value is correct? `top` command or system monitor

screenshot of discrepancy between top and Systems Monitor

[image: Please refer top command screenshot]

[image: Please refer system monitor screenshot]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Top reports usage pr (virtual) cpu-core, so 2 cores with hyper-threadings gives 4 cpu's = 100%. System monitor reports 100% for the whole system.

Comment: @SorenA Thanks a lot..Basically top command returns the total cpu usage of all cores while System monitor reports average of that isn't it? Am I correct?

Comment: more or less ... what I tried to say was that in top each virtual cpu counts as 100%, so if you have 2 cores with hyper threading it will count as 400%. System monitor counts the whole system as 100%, so one virtuel cpu is 25%.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that in System Monitor Preferences you have `Divide CPU Usage by CPU Count` enabled.